# JAXB how to deal with the header of XML response

Tags: jaxb

I want to map the xml response to JAVA class, but how should I deal with the header?

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="yes"?>
<ns: someProperty xmlns: ns="http://example.namespace.com">
  <ns: errorMsg>OK</ns: errorMsg>
  <ns: list>
    <ns: version>777</ns: version>
  </ns: list>
</ns: someProperty>
```

Comment: If the header is valid, JAXB should have no problems with it. In this case your header looks invalid, but I think it will be considered a processing instruction and also ignored.
Do you actually experience any specific problem?

Comment: Are you sure there are no spaces in the header? Correct would be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`.